# Store a HashMap in a Hashmap in a database - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I want to store following data structure in a DB

```
private Map<String, Map<Long, SafeTimeAndReponse>> mapStringToMap;
```

I tried now several ways of implementations with several different error messages.

I tried it with a class which extends TreeMap, no success.

```
private HashMap<String, CopyExtrendsTreeMap<Long, SafeTimeAndReponse>> mapStringToMap;
```

I used Map and HashMap, no success.

```
private HashMap<String, TreeMap<Long, SafeTimeAndReponse>> mapStringToMap;

private Map<String, Map<Long, SafeTimeAndReponse>> mapStringToMap;
```

I changed the annotation in different ways and got always different error messages. So no matter what I did, it was wrong.

So instead of I give you now all attempts i tried, I copy my current classes and hope very much that someone can help.

The current Error with that is:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.algotest.AlgoTest.exvDB.mapStringToMap
```

But as I said, I already got rid of it and just landed at others, so I don't even know if I am at the wrong or right way.

**How you can help me:**

Please just tell me how I can store that above mentioned data structure.

I use **SpringBoot 1.5.4, Hibernate 5 and H2 DB**

**exvDB**

```
@Entity
public class exvDB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long exvDB_id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Map<String, Map<Long, SafeTimeAndReponse>> mapStringToMap;

    public exvDB(Map<String, Map<Long, SafeTimeAndReponse>> mapStringToMap) {
        this.mapStringToMap= mapStringToMap;
    }

    public exvDB() {
    }

    public Map<String, Map<Long, SafeTimeAndReponse>> getMapStringToMap()() {
        return mapStringToMap;
    }

    public void setMapStringToMap(Map<String, Map<Long, SafeTimeAndReponse>> mapStringToMap) {
        this.mapStringToMap= mapStringToMap;
    }

    public Long getExvDB_id() {
        return exvDB_id;
    }

    public void setExvDB_id(Long exvDB_id) {
        this.exvDB_id = exvDB_id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        exvDB poloDB = (exvDB) o;

        return exvDB_id != null ? exvDB_id.equals(poloDB.exvDB_id) : poloDB.exvDB_id == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return exvDB_id != null ? exvDB_id.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

**ExvDBRepo**

```
@Repository
public interface ExvDBRepo extends CrudRepository<exvDB, Long> {
}
```

**SafeTimeAndReponse**

```
@Entity
public class SafeTimeAndReponse {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long safeTimeAndResponse_id;

    private String firstResponse;
    private String secondResponse;
    private long timeEnd;
    private long timePlus15;
    private long timePlus30;

    public SafeTimeAndReponse(String firstResponse, String secondResponse, long timeEnd, long timePlus15, long timePlus30) {
        this.firstResponse = firstResponse;
        this.secondResponse = secondResponse;
        this.timeEnd = timeEnd;
        this.timePlus15 = timePlus15;
        this.timePlus30 = timePlus30;
    }

    public long getTimeEnd() {
        return timeEnd;
    }

    public void setTimeEnd(long timeEnd) {
        this.timeEnd = timeEnd;
    }

    public SafeTimeAndReponse() {
    }

    public String getFirstResponse() {
        return firstResponse;
    }

    public void setFirstResponse(String firstResponse) {
        this.firstResponse = firstResponse;
    }

    public long getTimePlus15() {
        return timePlus15;
    }

    public void setTimePlus15(long timePlus15) {
        this.timePlus15 = timePlus15;
    }

    public long getTimePlus30() {
        return timePlus30;
    }

    public void setTimePlus30(long timePlus30) {
        this.timePlus30 = timePlus30;
    }

    public Long getSafeTimeAndResponse_id() {
        return safeTimeAndResponse_id;
    }

    public void setSafeTimeAndResponse_id(Long safeTimeAndResponse_id) {
        this.safeTimeAndResponse_id = safeTimeAndResponse_id;
    }

    public String getSecondResponse() {
        return secondResponse;
    }

    public void setSecondResponse(String secondResponse) {
        this.secondResponse = secondResponse;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        SafeTimeAndReponse that = (SafeTimeAndReponse) o;

        if (timeEnd != that.timeEnd) return false;
        if (timePlus15 != that.timePlus15) return false;
        if (timePlus30 != that.timePlus30) return false;
        if (safeTimeAndResponse_id != null ? !safeTimeAndResponse_id.equals(that.safeTimeAndResponse_id) : that.safeTimeAndResponse_id != null)
            return false;
        if (firstResponse != null ? !firstResponse.equals(that.firstResponse) : that.firstResponse != null)
            return false;
        return secondResponse != null ? secondResponse.equals(that.secondResponse) : that.secondResponse == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = safeTimeAndResponse_id != null ? safeTimeAndResponse_id.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (firstResponse != null ? firstResponse.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (secondResponse != null ? secondResponse.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (int) (timeEnd ^ (timeEnd >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + (int) (timePlus15 ^ (timePlus15 >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + (int) (timePlus30 ^ (timePlus30 >>> 32));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please, please, please adhere to the Java naming conventions. In addition, variable names like `hashMap` are vague and unhelpful and likely to wrongly imply an implementation, while failing to document role.

Comment: TIP:In my idea you can convert your HashMap to a JSON string, save JSON string to your db. When you need you can convert it back to HashMap. `Gson` can help you with that, see [reference](https://www.java2novice.com/java-json/google-gson/map-to-json/)

Comment: Try reifying `Map<Long, SafeTimeAndReponse>`.  Declare it as a class.  If nothing else, it should make it easier to "control" the DB mappings.

Comment: @Stephen C yes I did so over the last 12 hours and it's finally working like that. But I am still curious how it would work with a Map in a Map. But using hours of google I think it is just not possible.